# 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject. - Figuring out the issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having a rough time attempting to figure this out. This is the code for my first game on my own, whenever I run the program it returns:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Actionscript', Frame 2, Line 95, Column 36    1067:
>   Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type
>   flash.display:DisplayObject.

I've attempted to switch things around everywhere and I cannot figure out how to fix it. Browsing around I noticed something about mixing up instances and classes, however I am VERY new at this and am not sure about the differences between them and where to begin to fix that problem. Here is the entirety of my code below.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


stop();

var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
addChild(container);

//Make the player move
function playerMovement (event:Event):void
{
playerMC.y = stage.mouseY
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playerMovement);
//-----

//Make playerLasers work
function playerShoot (event:MouseEvent):void
{
var playerLaser:MovieClip = new playerLaserMC;
playerLaser.y = playerMC.y + 69;
playerLaser.x = playerMC.x + 125;
container.addChild(playerLaser);
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playerShoot);
//add damage dealt here - 

//--------

//Spawn random enemies
function addEnemy(event:Event)
{

var sendEnemy:Number = Math.random();
if (sendEnemy<=.01)
{
    var enemyGenerator:Number = Math.random();
    var minY:uint = 0;
    var maxY:uint = 300;
    var rangeY = maxY - minY;
    var randomY:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*rangeY) + minY
}

    if (enemyGenerator <=.25)
    {
        var newEnemy1:MovieClip = new enemyType1();
        newEnemy1.x = 100;
        newEnemy1.y = randomY;
        container.addChild(newEnemy1);
    }
    else if(enemyGenerator>.25, enemyGenerator<=.5)
    {
        var newEnemy2:MovieClip = new enemyType2();
        newEnemy2.x = 100;
        newEnemy2.y = randomY;
        container.addChild(newEnemy2);
    }
    else if(enemyGenerator>.5, enemyGenerator<=.75)
    {
        var newEnemy3:MovieClip = new enemyType3();
        newEnemy3.x = 100;
        newEnemy3.y = randomY;
        container.addChild(newEnemy3);
    }
    else if(enemyGenerator>.75, enemyGenerator<=1)
    {
        var newEnemy4:MovieClip = new enemyType4();
        newEnemy4.x = 200;
        newEnemy4.y = randomY;
        container.addChild(newEnemy4);
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, addEnemy);
//--------

//Destoy Enemies
function destroyEnemy(event:Event):void
{
if (container.hitTestObject(enemyType1))
{
    trace ("Hit Enemy");

}
else if (container.hitTestObject(enemyType2))
{
    trace ("Hit Enemy");

}
    else if (container.hitTestObject(enemyType3))
{
    trace ("Hit Enemy");

}
    else if (container.hitTestObject(enemyType4))
{
    trace ("Hit Enemy");

}

}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, destroyEnemy);
```

Comment: Could you clearify your exact question. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`enemyType1` is a `class` not a `variable`, therefore you cannot write:

```
if (container.hitTestObject(enemyType1)) {}
```

You have created an instance of the class `enemyType1` named `newEnemy1`:

```
var newEnemy1:enemyType1 = new enemyType1();
newEnemy1.x = 100;
newEnemy1.y = randomY;
container.addChild(newEnemy1);
```

And you call this instance through its variable:

```
if (container.hitTestObject(newEnemy1)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar example, and the issue was solved. However, the problem with this is that if you add `newEnemy1` within the `container`, the event of `hitTestObject` loop repeats. When you run the program you can see that the output window has

```
follow..
Hit Enemy
Hit Enemy
Hit Enemy
Hit Enemy
Hit Enemy
...
```

because `playerLaser` and `newEnemy1` are both in the `container`.
I solved the problem like so:

**Replace this line...**

```
container.addChild(newEnemy1);
```

**with**

```
addChild(newEnemy1);
```

I hope this can help you.